# Environment variables in github actions

Tags: github, environment-variables, github-actions, building-github-actions

I want to pass maven image version as as env variable but when i am trying to access that env.MAVEN_VERSION variable getting error

**Error- The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/Merge.yaml (Line: 13 image:) Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within expression: env.MAVEN_VERSION**

Yaml File ---

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

env:
  MAVEN_VERSION: maven:3.8.6-jdk-11
  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: ${{ env.MAVEN_VERSION }}
    steps:
    - name: Env Variable
      run: echo ${{ env.MAVEN_VERSION }}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While `env` is not available, outputs from previous jobs are.
Consider the following example

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

env:
  MAVEN_VERSION: maven:3.8.6-jdk-11
  
jobs:
  prepare-image:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
       - run: echo "null"
    outputs:
      image: ${{ env.MAVEN_VERSION }}

  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [prepare-image]
    container:
      image: ${{ needs.prepare-image.outputs.image }}
    steps:
    - name: Echo output
      run: echo ${{ needs.prepare-image.outputs.image }}
```

Comment: I had to add a placeholder step in the `prepare-image` job.

```No steps defined in `steps` and no workflow called in `uses` for the following jobs: prepare-image```

Comment: for this example to run you need to add a step for the job **prepare-image**

`steps:
      - run: echo "null"`

Comment: Really weird, but worked for me. I cannot get why env is not available there, but this handy hack solved my similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set your environment variables before jobs:

```yaml
name: Deploy to Github pages
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - main

env:
  MAVEN_VERSION: maven:3.8.6-jdk-11
  API_KEY: ${{secrets.API_KEY}}
  ...

jobs:
  deploy:
...
```

If you want to add secret from Github actions then go to the following route on github and set your secrets,

> Github > Your project > Settings > Secrets and variables > actions

[image: Go to the actions]

Go to the Actions and click on `New repository secret` to set an environment variable.

[image: Click on New repository secret]

Answer (score -6):

> when i am trying to access that...

That's not what the error is telling you about. The error `Unrecognized named-value: 'env'` is telling you that GitHub is not recognizing the YAML you wrote at line 13. It's a syntax error.

In a GitHub workflow you can use `env` either in `jobs.<job_id>.env` or in `jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].env`. See [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#env) for details.

This YAML should work:

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: ${{ env.MAVEN_VERSION }}
    steps:
      - name: Env Variable
        env:
          MAVEN_VERSION: maven:3.8.6-jdk-11
        run: echo ${{ env.MAVEN_VERSION }}
```

Also, note that when you only specify a container image, [you can omit the image keyword](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-running-a-job-within-a-container).

Comment: The yaml file u shared is not working still getting same error

Comment: when trying to access the env object of worflow level at                                         
 container:
      image: ${{ env.MAVEN_VERSION }}

Comment: ah ok, then move `env:` and `MAVEN_VERSION:` below `runs-on:`. Keep `env:` at the same level of `runs-on:`

Comment: still getting same error