# GitHub Actions if:

Tags: if-statement, github-actions

I want check if the commit message is not [RELEASE] but [PATCH], [MINOR] or [MAJOR].
I define all as Environment Variables.

`But when I run the workflow i get the error: Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within expression: env.PATCH == 'true'

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for help

```
env:
COMMIT_MSG: ${{ github.event.head_commit.message }} 
PATCH: ${{ startsWith(github.event.head_commit.message, '[PATCH]') || 'false' }} 
MINOR: ${{ startsWith(github.event.head_commit.message, '[MINOR]') || 'false' }} 
MAJOR: ${{ startsWith(github.event.head_commit.message, '[MAJOR]') || 'false' }} 

if: "!startsWith(github.event.head_commit.message, '[RELEASE]') && (${{ env.PATCH == 'true' }} || ${{env.MINOR == 'true' }} || ${{ env.MAJOR == 'true' }})"
```

I hope somebody can fix my Line of Code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73797254/environment-variables-in-github-actions

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that the syntax at your yaml file is correct.
env variables can only be accessed within steps, not within jobs or outside them so it should be:

```
jobs:
  job:
    steps:
      - name: step
        if: ${{ env.PATCH == 'true ... }}
```